# Using the function "find", of a set of struct, by passing just one attribute of the struct?

Tags: c++, struct, find, set

Is it possible to use the function "find", of a set of struct, by passing just one attribute of the struct?

The structs and the operators < are defined below:

```
struct ARCO_TEMPO {
    Arco a;
    int slotTimeU; // momento que sai do vertice u do arco
    int slotTimeV; // momento que chega no vertice v do arco
    int order;
    ARCO_TEMPO () {};
    ARCO_TEMPO (const ARCO_TEMPO& obj): a(obj.a), slotTimeU(obj.slotTimeU), slotTimeV(obj.slotTimeV), order(obj.order) {};
    ARCO_TEMPO (Arco _a, int _slotTimeU, int _slotTimeV, int _order) : a(_a), slotTimeU(_slotTimeU), slotTimeV(_slotTimeV), order(_order) {}    

};

struct PATH {

    set<ARCO_TEMPO> rota;
    float COST;

};

bool operator<(const ARCO_TEMPO& obj1, const ARCO_TEMPO& obj2) {
    if (obj1.slotTimeU < obj2.slotTimeU) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (obj1.slotTimeU == obj2.slotTimeU && obj1.slotTimeV < obj2.slotTimeV) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if (obj1.slotTimeU == obj2.slotTimeU && obj1.slotTimeV == obj2.slotTimeV && obj1.a.i < obj2.a.i) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                if (obj1.slotTimeU == obj2.slotTimeU && obj1.slotTimeV == obj2.slotTimeV &&obj1.a.i == obj2.a.i && obj1.a.j < obj2.a.j ) {
                    return true;
                }
                else{ 
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

bool operator<(const PATH& obj1, const PATH& obj2) {
    if (obj1.COST < obj2.COST) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (obj1.COST == obj2.COST && obj1.rota < obj2.rota) {
            return true;
        }
        else{ 
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a variable PATH, called as aux_p. Then I have the attribute rota of this PATH (aux_p.rota). I want to find the "position" in the set rota (aux_p.rota), in which the attribute order is equal a specific value.

I tried the lines below, but it doesn't work:

```
set<ARCO_TEMPO>::iterator it;
int orderAux = aux_p.rota.size();
it = aux_p.find(it->orderAux)
```

How can I use a second container unordered_map to this works?
Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Use of uninitialized iterator: `it->orderAux`.

Comment: Please be sure that you provide [mcve]. The current example is not valid: ARCO_TEMPO::orderAux is not declared, `PATH::find` is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible. Either iterate through all set elements from `begin()` to `end()`, or use a second container `unordered_map<int>`.

BTW `ARCO_TEMPO::orderAux` and `PATH::find` are not declared.